# Error while installing opencv with cuda on Macbook

Tags: macos, opencv, cuda, cmake

I've installed Cuda on my macbook and now I'm trying to install opencv and I follow the instructions I'm given through various tutorials.

When I get to the point of writing `make -j`" in the same folder where the opencv tarball is downloaded I get this error:

```
Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o
[ 18%] Built target IlmImf
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
clang: error: no input files
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o.cmake:206 (message):
  Error generating
  /Users/nickververis/Documents/opencv-2.4.6.1/opencv-2.4.6.1/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o


make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The thing is that I've even tried to change the path of `CUDA_HOST_COMPILER` by typing
`cmake -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc` as many other posts suggest me to, but I've got no results because I'm still getting error when typing `make -j8`.

Comment: Nikos, allakse to name se latin form wste na mporei kaneis na se kanei tag kata to reply.

Comment: NVCC needs gcc as its compiler. Here it is using clang. Google around to figure out how to change that.

Comment: I'm trying to change it by typing cmake -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc but I'm not sure I'm doing it in the correct folder.On which folder should I run this command?

Comment: I ran this command ( -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc) on the same folder where the CmakeLists.txt were created (by running cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"..) and it looks like its completed:
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
But now once more when i move into the build folder and try to "make -j8" I get this same error:
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
clang: error: no input files
So it looks like I haven't really changed the compiler...